# Nuxt pre-rendering command fails to generate static routes

Tags: vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

With Nuxt set in `spa` mode, `npm run generate` should automatically generate a `html` file for each static route (meaning for each `.vue` file present in `pages/` folder).

For me it doesn't. It only generates a `200.html` file (I don't understand what this file is for btw), but nothing else, not even `index.html`!

Any suggestion?

Note: strangely enough, I can make the generation of dynamic routes work if I add the code below in my config file, in which case a `html` file is generated for each dynamic route, but still no static route and no `index.html`...

```
generate: {
  routes: () => axios.get('http://example.com/wp/wp-json/projects/v1/posts')
    .then(res => res.data.map((project) => `/project/${project.ID}/${project.post_name}`))
},
```

Also if I set router to `hash` mode, then I get a `index.html` file but no static or dynamic routes are generated (the app works though).

Answer (score 2):

Check the output from running `nuxt generate`, my guess is that there are error messages such as

```
ℹ Prerendering 5 initial routes with crawler
  ├─ / (427ms) (Error: [500] )
  ├─ /200.html (411ms)
  ├─ /404.html (410ms)
  ├─ /... (2ms)
  ├─ /... (2ms)                                                                                            
Errors prerendering:
  ├─ / (500)
```

where `/ (427ms) (Error: [500] )` and `/ (500)` are in red. Basically, there is a problem with the index.vue page. I haven't found a way for the system to tell me what the problem is (Nitro log somewhere?). I kept removing code from index.vue until the error went away to pin down what the problem was, quite painful.

One example that could cause the page to fail render: using `document`, e.g. `document.title`. The workaround for this is to use `useSeoMeta({ title: () => ... })` instead to set the page title.

Btw, this is Nuxt 3. The original question might be related to Nuxt 2.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this behaviour with a new project created by running `npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>`.  Additionally, I was able to add a new page, in SPA mode, and have it generated by `nuxt generate`.

Double check your project configuration, make sure you're on the latest version of nuxt, and if the problem persists, include a minimum example that reproduces the issue.

As for the `200.html` file, this is the [fallback page](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/#fallback).

> When running a SPA it is more idiomatic to use a 200.html, as it's the only file necessary as no other routes are generated.

I can't confirm, but this hints at your issue of no `index.html` being generated, since according to this, `200.html` is the only file required in SPA mode.

And lastly, is SPA mode what you're really after?  Normally, these apps only have the one HTML file, and it is all rendered client side.  It sounds to me that you're after `nuxt generate` with the mode set to `universal`, which renders all static routes, and all supplied dynamic routes, for static hosting.